# Solution of equation with given constraint.

Tags: differential-geometry

I solved eq.

$-\partial^2 A^\nu + M \epsilon^{\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\rho A_\sigma=0$

Where $A^\nu= \epsilon^\nu(k) e^{ik\cdot x}$ $and$ $ \nu=0,1,2 (2+1 D$ $case)$
and constraints are $k_\mu \epsilon^\mu(k)=0$ and $k_\mu k^\mu = M^2$.

In rest frame $k_\mu = (M,0,0)$ the solution I get is

$\epsilon^\mu(k)= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(0,1,i)$ but the solution given as

$\epsilon^\mu(k)= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(0,1,i\frac{M}{|M|})$

I am not getting the difference. Whats wrong??????

Comment: @Mike Miller I am getting no response. What possible tags can be added so that max users could see this question?

Comment: I do not know enough about your question to suggest tags, sorry. I removed the tag class field theory only because that refers to a part of algebraic number theory that is unrelated to what you've written here.